# Joomla form in editor does not find the associated php action file

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I am new to Joomla and I am struggling to get a form going. I created the form using the editor of an Extra Field. Now in the form I am calling the action php file:

```
<form action="email1.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

Unfortunately, nothing is happening and I suspect that I put the php file in the wrong directory. Looking at the file manager I have no idea where to put the php file. Can anybody tell me where I have to copy the php file to so that the editor can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to create a folder on the main directory of your website to collect your own datas/pages without messing joomla original file.
Let's call it "myfolder" and copy email1.php in it.

Now you can go to 'www.mysite.com/myfolder/email1.php' and expect some kind of result.

Now modify your code to avoid that mysterious relative path and use this instead :

```
<form action="/myfolder/email1.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

This should do the trick.

Edit : this is a generic answer, not joomla specific.

Comment: well, thanks a lot. I was approaching this totally wrong, whilst the answer is so simple. Thanks for getting me out of my "thinking knot".